# Background fading-in from the bottom based on a range slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not very experienced but what I'm trying to do is this. When the page loads I don't have a background but on the right of the page I have a slider that goes from 1 to 100. I am looking for a way to make a background that starts appearing from the bottom of the container and goes all the way up when the value 100 of the slider is reached.

**HTML**

```
 <section class= "pageContainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" name="slider" class="vSlider">
 </section>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find the right idea on what the javascript should change so that I get the desired effect . Can anyone help me?

**JS**

```
$('input[name=slider]').on('change', function () {
});
```

**FINAL WORKING SOLUTION :**

```
// Variable declaration
var heightStore = [];
var heightProg = [];
var rowHeight;
var count = 0;
heightProg[0] = 0;

// Store each div height in an array
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each($('.row'),function(){
    rowHeight = $(this).height();
    heightStore[count] = rowHeight;
    count++;
    heightProg[count] = heightProg[count-1]+rowHeight;
  })
});
heightProg.reverse();

// Calculate how many divs
var ct = $('.pageContainer').children().size() - 1;

// Function to execute on slider value change
$('input[name=slider]').on('input', function () {

if (!$("div").hasClass("pageContainer")) $("div").addClass("pageContainer");
  {for(var i=0;i<=ct;i++)
      if($(this).val() == Math.round(100/ct)*i)
      $("div").css({ "background-position" : "0px "+ heightProg[i] +"px"
                   });
  };
});
```

Comment: if you are using the jquery ui slider you can use the [slide change event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change)

Comment: Four close votes, four different close reasons... and the question has an answer.  Guess I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this. Tested only in FF tho

```
$('input[name=slider]').on('input', function () {
  if (!$("body").hasClass("bg_img")) $("body").addClass("bg_img");    
  $("body").css({ "background-position" : "0px "+ ($(window).height() * (100 - $(this).val()) / 100) +"px"});
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pJe39/)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. just have to update it for my code. Thanks, i'll post the final working solution

Answer (score 0):

I created some fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4rZq/

**JS:**

```
$('input[name=slider]').on('change', function () {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,' + (this.value / 100) + ')');
});
```

Let me know, if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: something in the same idea but 'growing' from the bottom of the container to the top of the container it sits in.